# Analysis of nodeload result

Tags: node.js, nodeload

Can anyone explain me the nodeload result below.

```
./nl.js -c 1 -n 10000 -i 1 "http://localhost:3000/

Server:                                 localhost:3000
HTTP Method:                            GET
Document Path:                          /
Concurrency Level:                      1
Number of requests:                     10000
Body bytes transferred:                 3516274
Elapsed time (s):                       1172.70
Requests per second:                    9.23
Mean time per request (ms):             107.95
Time per request standard deviation:    187.76

Percentages of requests served within a certain time (ms)
Min: 38
Avg: 107.9
50%: 84
95%: 141
99%: 1076
Max: 5820
```

How is the percentage of requests calculated?

Thanks

Comment: It keeps track of the time it takes to serve each request, and computes the quartiles in a standard fashion (50% = average of 5000th and 5001st request, 95% and 99% defined similarly)

Comment: What is Min,Avg and Max?

Comment: @user87267867 min/avg/max number of milliseconds that it took to complete the requests (so the fastest request was completed in 38ms, the slowest in 5820ms, and average for all requests is 107.9ms).